# Error in Grails application .yml

Tags: grails, yaml

I'm using `Grails 3.3.2` using `intellij` IDE , when i try to run my application I got the below error:

```
 Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: expected '<document start>', but found 
BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 105, column 1:
hibernate:
```

this is generated from the `application.yml` file , here is the part that is complaining about:

```
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
       #    converters:
       #      encoding : UTF-8


    exceptionresolver:
        params:
            exclude:
                - password
                - creditCard

        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none

#      endpoints:
#       jmx:
#        unique-names: true

# logging:
#   config: '../config/logback.groovy' #${userHome}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DB configs
hibernate: // this is the line it's complaining about 
   cache:
       # queries: false
      use_second_level_cache: false
      use_query_cache: false

  dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
#    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
#    username: sa
#    password: ''

 environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
#   url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            username: myusername
            password: mypassword
            url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/DB_New
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
#            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            jndiName : "jdbc/mysqlDBConnLocal"
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5

#--------------------------------------------
```

What may causing this error? anything was missed? and is there a way to format `yml` file in `intellij` or any other application can help me in formatting `yml` files .

Comment: Can you give some context to the part of the YAML you posted (content in front of it) and show which line is line 105?

Comment: @flyx line `105` is `hibernate:`

Comment: the error is probably before that line.

Comment: @flyx this is what before that line `#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# DB configs`

Comment: And before that? Just edit the question and show the 5 previous lines or so. There's no error in the YAML you showed so far.

Comment: @flyx i edited the original post